# Linux machine is getting disconnected from windows domain controller frequently

Tags: linux, active-directory

My Linux server is getting disconnected from windows DC for every 30 days.
Not sure where I need to check either AD or Linux sever config files

Answer (score 2):

Hi this occurs when the maximum machine account password age expires.

It sounds like you're running into an issue with the default SSSD-AD value for `ad_maximum_machine_account_password_age` of 30 days before attempting a renew which is greater than what your domain policy is set to. Try dropping the `ad_maximum_machine_account_password_age` flag to 15 or 10 days depending on personal preference.

It is also important to run RSOP to determine what value actually is for your domain.

Here is some appropriate reading to help confirm this statement and address the relevant required config.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/domain-member-maximum-machine-account-password-age

https://funinit.wordpress.com/2017/11/29/how-sssd-updates-machine-account-password/

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/sssd-ad.5.html

Comment: I couldn't file any configuration file like sssd-ad under sssd direcotry. All I see is only sssd.conf file...